# The world is flat. Why are they all lying?

Tags: politics, earth-like, secret-society

*Backstory : I feel like more and more persons assume the world is flat. Their arguments are flooding the internet, showing how obvious it is that the "round world" is a lie. 
Science, oceans and space exploration proved that the earth is more a sphere than a disc. But, well, I didn't see the world from space myself, I'm only believing in informations. Maybe i'm the one falling in the Big Lie, as i'm too lazy to make an experiment to prove the earth round by myself. But why ?*

For this question, I assume our world is flat. Everything that prove the world is a sphere is an elaborate lie.

**What's the interest of making mankind think the earth is not flat ? What's the goal of this global conspiracy ?**

Secondary question : Who could be responsible of that ? "They" would need a lot of money and influence, and a very good reason.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for conspiracy theories which lead to the world being duped into believing a lie, or are you also interested in arguments as rational arguments like those I might use when debating with a flat-earther?

Comment: I'm interrested with both =)

Answer (score 7):

Flat Earth would contradict the direct personal experiences of every person on this planet. Faking that a flat earth is instead a sphere would require **magic**.

Thus it would by necessity be done by powerful magicians. A likely reason would be to fool us into believing that science works and thus prevent people from learning magic and competing with the illuminated ones.

You could replace magicians with demons and their human servants and adjust motive into making people turn away from God by obfuscating God's creation from them.

Answer (score 3):

I take the question to be who benefits from the round earth theory?
The answer is the people who live on the square corners countries south of Antartica. [image] 
The bible says they are angels but who can trust the bible?

They control the wind and don't want lesser species like humans to mess with their tech.

Answer (score 1):

Because Mecca is actually the center of this flat world. Europeans could not stand that truth, so they decided to elaborate a big lie.

However, it becomes clear that by making any other places in the center, they would create tensions, and could even make someone wants to reveal the truth. A spherical world was a smart compromise.

Comment: I have a map proving Jerusalem is the center. http://f.hypotheses.org/wp-content/blogs.dir/1447/files/2013/12/Bunting-Map-Replication-by-Darian-site-Keilo-Jack.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the true nature of Earth would be very, very difficult. How do you explain [Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes#Measurement_of_the_Earth.27s_circumference)?

- A flat Earth would have a backside, as large as the Earth we know. To get there you have to cross the rim or dig tunnels through the disk. What is hiding on the other side?
- A flat Earth would have a rim. Can you fall off? Can you launch spacecraft with little energy expenditure? Then knowledge of the location of the rim gives untold riches from asteroid mining.
- A flat Earth would mean that physics as we know it are wrong. Who knows the "true" nature of the universe and do they benefit from this exclusive knowledge?
- On a related note, if there is a God and if this God wants people to have faith in Him rather than proof of Him, then He would have to try and hide this proof. For this reason He sets things up so that flatworlders believe that they live on a sphere.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP asked for motivations, not the problems with keeping the conspiracy.

Comment: The first sentence is not an answer but the four points are showing partial answers.

Comment: Eratosthenes is a tool of the "angels" sent to confuse us with his mathematical sophistry.

Comment: @Samuel, I thought that was clear. Hiding something on the backside, hiding the rim, hiding the true nature of the universe could all be motivations of various conspirators.

Comment: @o.m. I had the same thought as Samuel at first, your first sentence is tricky. And I know there are looots of proofs. But some people keep thinking that the earth is flat.

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering from a serious psychosis. The rest of us don't think it's a sphere. We can see it's the inside of a torus. The old sphere is a long way away on the outside. Theres a telescope you can use if you want to look ar it. It looks like a small white pearl. Our ancestors messed it up really badly and most of the people died. Only us ellfors survived.

Now take these pills. You'll be feeling happier in the morning.